# Load and save images on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I Want to let the user chose images from his gallery and add them to the app, and i want the image to be saved on the local app storage, so should i create a Database for saving the pictures or just for saving the path to those pictures (refrence)

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you if you want to manage the references in a database, depending on your needs.

If you need to store plain pictures without anymore linked informations I would just go for path_provider's application Directory, as the example tells (https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider):

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```

And then just use the whole directory.

If you need to store more meta data, as e.g. like count of a picture or some origin url etc. then i would go for a sqlite database storing the references and meta data in a table.

Comment: what if i wanted to store a copy of that image in my app storage, is it possible

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant actually. Copying your image from your gallery to your ApplicationsDocumentsDirectory

Comment: ah okey so now i need to figure out how to save images on a Database